# Correlation with covariate in R

Tags: correlation, partial

I have 2 files. File1 contains gene expression- 300 samples(rows) and ~50k genes (50k columns), File2 contains MRI data -the same 300 samples and ~100 columns. I want to correlate GE data with MRI data controlling for covariate which is disease status (file3, status 0 or 1).

I have tried to use ppcor package, for 2 variables it worked:

```
pcor.test(file1$gene1, file2$var1, file3$status, method="pearson")
```

but I want to run for all variables, so I merged into 1 file, last columns being status:

```
sapply(1:(ncol(test)-1), function(x) sapply(1:(ncol(test)-1), function(y) {
     if (x == y) 1
     else pcor.test(test[,x], test[,y], test[,ncol(test)])$estimate
 }))
```

but had this error:

```
Error in solve.default(cvx) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.36939e-18
```

Am I doing this correctly? Is this a good method?

Thank you for suggestions and help
Georg

```
File1
         gene1 gene2 gene3 ...  gene50,000
Sample1  12   300    70             4000
Sample2  25   100    53             4500
Sample3  70  30      71             2000
...
Sample300 18 200     97             1765

File2

        var1 var2 var3 ...  var100
Sample1  5   1    170             200
Sample2  7   3    153             100
Sample3  7  18    130             34
...
Sample300 18 54   197             71
```

File3-STATUS

```
        status
Sample1  1
Sample2  1
Sample3  0
...
Sample300 1
```